# How to get results where all of the 'many' results match a condition?

Tags: sql, one-to-many

I've got a one to many relationship Item ID to Item Note. How do I write a query that returns only the Item IDs for which each and every note they have contains a a key word. Instead I'm getting the IDs even if one of the notes matches the condition. This is the query I'm getting the bad results with.

```
select

count (distinct I.IDs)

from

Items I
left join Item_Stats IS on I.ItemID = IS.FKItemID

where

I.Deleted = 0 and
IS.Deleted = 0 and
IS.Description like '%Bamboo%'
```

EDIT: I've edited the query a bit to simplify.

[image: example]

With the query I get as a result 1,3,6,9. What I need to get is 3 and 9.

Comment: Help us help you - please share your tables' structures, some sample data and the result you're trying to get for that sample.

Comment: Why `I.FKItemID is NULL`? Add some sample and expected data to your question.

Comment: I've edited the original post.

Comment: @cdaiga I'll remove that part so its not confusing. Its unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a join. You can simple fetch the data from the Item_stats table alone as shown below.

```
SELECT FKItemID
FROM Item_Stats
WHERE DELETED=0
GROUP BY FKItemID
HAVING COUNT(*)=SUM(IF(UPPER(Description) LIKE '%BAMBOO%',1,0));
```

Comment: Cool idea, I get it, but this returns an error, that expects something on the last bracket. I've no idea why when every bracket is closed properly. Any idea about that?

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just FYI it worked when I added a part so it became: HAVING COUNT(*)=SUM(UPPER(Description) LIKE '%BAMBOO%' than 1 else 0 end);

Comment: Thank you, I just adjusted my query!